# How to get innerHTML when clicking an <a> and inserting that innerHTML on another HTML page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have an image gallery, each gallery item has the picture, a title, and description. I want to be able to click on any of these gallery items and have a "detail" page load and fill in dynamically the image, title, and description. How can I do this?

I tried getting each of the values inside the divs with.innerHTML, but how do I "send" these values to the other HTML page?

You can see exactly what I want here:
http://madebymorro.com/web_majosecastano/nieve.html
This is the image gallery, only 1 item is active, the first one under "2008".
You can see that when you click on it, a detail page opens:
http://madebymorro.com/web_majosecastano/detalle.html

This is what I want to achieve, but not having to create a detail page manually for each one of the image gallery items. I want the detail page to fill in with the info coming from the galley HTML page.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] the question to include a [mre] because once you've fixed your site that link will no longer illustrated what you are describing in the question and one of the goals of Stack Overflow is for the questions to help other people in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your pages into php and create only one detail page  when you click on any  gallery item pass the id or title of that gallery in  tag and access that id using url query parameter or any other method

```
   <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="gellery-block">
<a href="detail-page.php?id=1">
<img src="random-img.jpg"></img>
</a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="gellery-block">
<a href="detail-page.php?id=2">
<img src="random-img.jpg"></img>
</a>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="gellery-block">
<a href="detail-page.php?id=3">
<img src="random-img.jpg"></img>
</a>
</div>
</div>
```

and in detail-page.php access id using query paremeter and then access result using id and print in detail page

To access id using query parameter add code in detail page like this

```
<?php $galleryId= $_GET['id']; ?>
```

here you will get gallery id

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. It's not clear to me, I'm not familiar with PHP, how to get the image, title and description and pass it on to the detail.html.
I see the logic in having each <a href> with a specific id, but how do I "store" the image, title and description and fill in the detail page dynamically?
Thanks!

Comment: I got to the point where I can store into variables each image/title/description of the gallery item I click, with this JS code:

`document.querySelectorAll('.grid_gallery_item').forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', () => {
      const imgSrc = item.querySelector('img').src
      const title = item.querySelector('.ttl').innerText
      const size = item.querySelector('.size').innerText
      const detailTtl = document.getElementById('detail_ttl');
      console.log(detailTtl);
    })
  })`

But now my question is ¿how do I pass this variables to the detail.html?

Comment: @madebymorro please learn database then you will get clear idea 
thanks